# Only unique objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is this possible to use a feature similar to this below that will return both properties without having to create a second array.
The second property Name will always be the same.

```
const data = [{
    Group: 'A',
    Name: 'SEAN'
}, {
    Group: 'B',
    Name: 'PAUL'
}, {
    Group: 'A',
    Name: 'SEAN'
}, {
    Group: 'B',
    Name: 'PAUL'
}];

let unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.Group))];
console.log(unique);

return ["A", "B"]
```

https://codepen.io/vlad-bezden/pen/OMEXJz

I am trying to return

```
  [{
   Group: 'A',
   Name: 'SEAN'
   }, 
 {
   Group: 'B',
   Name: 'PAUL'
 }]
```

Comment: How does the code above not accomplish what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you want to return `['A','B']` or something else?

Comment: Try this [remove duplicates from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicates from an array of objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to remove duplicate objects from an array and get an array of unique objects you can use `.reduce`. Here I use `.reduce` to create an object of keys. The keys are a combination of both the `Group` and `Name`, which allows you to check if your reduced object has the value within it already.

Lastly, I use `Object.keys` to get the unique objects stored as the values at each combination.

See example below:

```js
'use strict'

const data = [{
    Group: 'A',
    Name: 'SEAN'
}, {
    Group: 'B',
    Name: 'PAUL'
}, {
    Group: 'A',
    Name: 'SEAN'
}, {
    Group: 'B',
    Name: 'PAUL'
}];

let unique = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {Group, Name}) => {
  const key = `${Group}:${Name}`;
  !(key in acc) && (acc[key] = {Group, Name});
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(unique);
```

This will give you a unique array of objects by checking *both* the `Group` and the `Name`

Comment: when i try to use this code i get an error saying "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions". on the line key in acc ? acc : acc[key] = {Group, Name};

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `forEach`

Here the idea is `included` is used to keep track of the groups added into `op`. Then we check if the group is already in the `included` object, if it is we do nothing, otherwise we add it to `op`.

```js
const data = [{Group: 'A', Name: 'SEAN'}, { Group: 'B', Name: 'PAUL'}, { Group: 'A',Name: 'SEAN'}, {Group: 'B',Name: 'PAUL'}];

let op = []
let included = {}

data.forEach((e)=>{
  if( !included[e.Group] ){
    op.push(e)
    included[e.Group] = true
  }
})

console.log(op)
```